# Trying to deploy Angular App to GitHub Pages

Tags: angular, deployment, github-pages

I'm trying to deploy my Angular app (I am using node.js 14.20.0 ) to GitHub pages. I have successfully installed:

```
npm i angular-cli-ghpages
```

but when I run :

```
ng deploy --base-href=https://rejkid.com.github.io/ScheduleMeFrontEnd/
```

as suggested in the article [link](https://atdilakshan.medium.com/deploy-an-angular-app-to-github-pages-with-angular-cli-92a2d6fe6533#:%7E:text=The%20angular%2Dcli%2Dghpages%20package,ng%20add%20angular%2Dcli%2Dghpages) I am getting this error:

```
Error: Unknown argument: base-href
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `"npm i" !== "ng add"`

Comment: `ng add` fails to install `angular-cli-ghpages` so I tried this way suggested in another post

Comment: Fails how, exactly? Just installing the dependency isn't necessarily going to update the configuration appropriately to tell Angular CLI how to use that additional command. Include the information in your post - what error, what other post.

Comment: When I do `ng add angular-cli-ghpages` it complains about the missing package ` @angular-devkit/core`. After I installed that package when I run again `ng add angular-cli-ghpages' it returns an error `Unexpected token '??='`

Comment: [Edit] the question. [Based on that error](https://node.green/#ES2021-features-Logical-Assignment) it sounds like you're using Node <=14, which is well out of support (in general, but also [by Angular 16+](https://angular.io/guide/versions#actively-supported-versions)).

Comment: I am using node.js 14.20.0 - ohh so this is a problem. Thank you. I will upgrade my angular to ver 17 and node v18.13.0

Comment: After upgrading to Angular ver 17 and node 18.18.2 still getting same error `Error: Unknown argument: base-href`

Comment: The angular docs has a different set of instructions for [deploying to Github pages](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#deploy-to-github-pages). Mainly, it doesn't use `ng deploy` but instead uses `ng build` and the output from that needs to be committed to the repo.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, but this worked for me.

Run the commands below in your terminal to build your app and deployed to ghpages:

- Install ghpages cli

```
npm i angular-cli-ghpages
```

- Build your app. Use `build` instead of `deploy`

```
ng build --base-href https://[username].github.io/[repo]/
```

- After your project build: run this command for to pick up the files from the build path (relative path to your local /dist directory in your repo).

```
ngh --dir=dist/[project-name]
```

- Finally you can find your project online.
  `https://[username].github.io/[repo-name]/`